# Symfony select form with conditon

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I want to create a form for a planning subscription. 1 The user can participate in 1 planning and can subscribe at 1 day. So if 1 user subscribes at the planningid: 1 and choose the Friday, it will be written in the DB like that:
User: planning_id:1 and planningday: 5.
So now we have a second user, who want's to subscribe at the same planning 1.
But now he can't choose the Friday because the first user already takes that day.
I want to display a form who show only the remainings days.

For nom i have created a simple form like that:

```
$form = $this->get('form.factory')->createBuilder(FormType::class, $user)
            ->add('planningday', ChoiceType::class, array(
                    'label' => 'Sélectionnez un jour',
                    'choices' => array(
                        'Lundi' => 1,
                        'Mardi' => 2,
                        'Mercredi' => 3,
                        'Jeudi' => 4,
                        'Vendredi' => 5
                    )
                ))
            ->add('planningcontent', TextType::class, array( 'label' => 'Description'))
            ->add('S\'inscrire au planning', SubmitType::class)
```

I want to improve this form but I have no idea on what I can do in this way.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up many to many in doctrine data-mapping:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional